# How to write http response outside of http.ListenAndServe handler?

Tags: http, go

I'm setting up a HTTP server in Go, telling the server to handle all requests with the putRequestOnQueue function:

```
http.ListenAndServe(":6776", *handler)
http.HandleFunc("/", putRequestOnQueue)
```

The job of putRequestOnQueue is to put the response writer on a queue, to be pulled off and used to return a response at some future time.

```
func putRequestOnQueue(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    RequestQueue.Put(responseWriter)
}
```

However, it appears that once the ResponseWriter goes out of scope, the server returns a 200. I'd imagine it does this because it figures "oh, the function you told me was gonna handle this request just lost the writer, so I'm just gonna spit back a 200."

But I don't want this behavior. I want to be able to write back when I choose, from another function. Is there a way I can write back a response from another function without the server prematurely returning a 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the handler returns, the server sends a reply/status. You'll need something like:

```
func putRequestOnQueue(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    RequestQueue.Put(responseWriter)
    waitForResponse()
}
```

In other words, `putRequestOnQueue` shouldn't return until the response is ready. You can use a channel, for example, or whatever else to do this waiting.

---

Note, however, that this isn't very idiomatic Go. In Go we don't do as much async patterns as in other languages, because goroutines are cheap. Each HTTP handler [is already called in a separate goroutine](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/on-concurrency-in-go-http-servers/), so you might as well use your handler to *do the work* rather than *dispatch the work to be done elsewhere*.

Comment: Thanks! I simplified the scenario in order to ask the question, but I'm really trying to limit the number of requests I send downstream to another server. I know it probably wouldn't make sense to queue requests if I was immediately sending back upstream. It's surprising to me there's not way to avoid this.

Comment: Just limit the number of requests sent to that server, then. Don't use async. Just have any pending goroutines wait until the service is available. Go already handles that for you. Async is invented for languages that don't have that flexibility.

Comment: @nickackerman42: the blog post I linked to near the bottom has a code sample for limiting the concurrency downstream

Comment: I understand returning the response in the handler by passing it a "go ahead" message to a channel is a possibility. However, because the handler is already responsible for placing the request on a queue, I was trying to let another function be responsible for writing back the actual response. Y'all may say that's not "idiomatic," and I value that opinion, but my question was whether this is possible. It sounds like it's not.

Comment: @nickackerman42: yes, it's possible. your handler can call a function with the response writer, or send it on a channel, but it *has to wait* for the function to finish its job, it can't just return and leave the function to run and write the result later

Comment: Mhm -- makes sense. I'm blocking on a "done" channel until the request is served. Thanks for the help.